# Collection view cell displaying wrong background color in some views

Tags: ios, swift

The background color supposedly rendered on Card D was rendered in Card A in a different row. This is weird because the background color of the card title is set at the same time as the background colors of the views behind it, but only the views behind don't render the right color, while the view on top renders the right color.

**Attached Screenshot-**

[image: screenshot]

Code from tableview:

```
let cell: BrowseReadTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath)
cell.update(properties: properties[indexPath.section]?)
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
return cell
```

Code from collectionview:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    typeBackground.backgroundColor = .clear
    for bgView in bgCollection { //bgCollection is the collection of cards behind this are the views that don't render the right color
        bgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
}

func update(resource: Resource, properties: CatalogProperties?) {

    if let cardColor = properties?.appearance?.cardHeader {
        if let bgColor = cardColor.backgroundColor {
            for bgView in bgCollection {
                bgView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(bgColor.rgb![0] / 255), green: CGFloat(bgColor.rgb![1] / 255), blue: CGFloat(bgColor.rgb![2] / 255), alpha: CGFloat(bgColor.alpha ?? 1))
            }

            typeBackground.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(bgColor.rgb![0] / 255), green: CGFloat(bgColor.rgb![1] / 255), blue: CGFloat(bgColor.rgb![2] / 255), alpha: CGFloat(bgColor.alpha ?? 1))
                
        }
        if let fgColor = cardColor.foregroundColor {
            typeLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(fgColor.rgb![0] / 255), green: CGFloat(fgColor.rgb![1] / 255), blue: CGFloat(fgColor.rgb![2] / 255), alpha: CGFloat(fgColor.alpha ?? 1))
        }

    } else {
        typeBackground.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(hexString: "#7C58C5")
        for bgView in bgCollection {
            bgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(hexString: "#7C58C5")
    }
}
```